# Removing rows with duplicate values based on variable number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.7

Consider the following table

---

### column1 | column2 | column3 | column4

a | b | 1 | 2
a | b | 2 | 3
a | c | 2 | 4

I want remove duplicates based on **cloumn1** and **column2** and keep only one such instance. Therefore the above table should look something like

a | b | 1 | 2
a | c | 2 | 4

I tried to Add Unique index like this

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `my_table` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `index1` (`column1` ASC, `column2` ASC);
```

This should have worked perfectly but

> As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.

So what are the alternatives for this scenario?

**NOTE:** This is not a duplicate question. I have searched before asking this. Please read in once again before marking as a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the duplicated rows

```
delete  my_table 
where id not in (select t.id from ( 
select min(id)  as id from my_table
group by column1, column2 ) as t )
```

Comment: This will give Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table  for update in FROM clause. A simple way to avoid it is delete my_table where id not in ( select t.id from( 
select min(id)  as id from my_table
group by column1, column2 ) as t). I am still accepting your answer, but for others update you answer

Comment: @AbhijithNagaraja   yes .. correct  i have update the answer